# How to filter a dataframe by another dataframe by row elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df_new is the actual data and I filtered df_new to obtain paypal_data. I want to filter df_new by paypal_data. But when filtering by created_at I just want to filter by month, day, year, without taking hours

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the column to just date first.

```
df_new["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df_new["created_at"]).dt.date
```